# WebSocket React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, websocket, autobahn

I'm new to `react native` moved from `ReactJS` I thought I can use same packages as my previous pure `Reactjs` app but I was wrong.

What I'm trying to do is to make a `websocket` connection.

I'm recently using [`autobahnJS`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobahn) package `WAMP2` in my ReactJS app but when I moved to react native it seems  `autobahnJS` doesn't support `react-native`

```
connectToSocketFunction = () =>{ // autobahn code
        let connection = new autobahn.Connection({ url: 'wss://api.example.com/websocket/', realm: 'Realm1', authmethods: ['jwt'] });
        connection.onopen = (session, detalis) => {

            session.subscribe('ChannelName', (data)=>console.log(data));
        };
```

Anyone know how does react native make socket connection based on my code?

I have tried [react-native-autobahnjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autobahnjs) doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The React Native documentation mentions support for WebSocket connections:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://host.com/path');

ws.onopen = () => {
  // connection opened
  ws.send('something'); // send a message
};

ws.onmessage = (e) => {
  // a message was received
  console.log(e.data);
};

ws.onerror = (e) => {
  // an error occurred
  console.log(e.message);
};

ws.onclose = (e) => {
  // connection closed
  console.log(e.code, e.reason);
};
```

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#websocket-support

You will most likely need to use other React Native based frameworks to fill in the gaps that Autobahn provided, e.g. session support and JWT authentication.

Comment: Do you know any frameworks to fill in the gaps like Autobahn?

Comment: It would require several different frameworks and code snippets which is going to be way outside the scope of this question.  You could alternatively fork AutoBahnJS and modify it to work with React Native.  [Here's](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-js/issues/321) an issue open on the AutoBahn GitHub that explains what you'd need to do.

Comment: Thank you Alex for your help

Comment: link is not working anymore, for anyone who need it https://reactnative.dev/docs/network#websocket-support